# I receive error: package com.google.ads.mediation.customevent does not exist error when adding admob to my xamarin forms project

Tags: forms, xamarin, admob

I receive 100 errors when adding admob to my Xamarin forms project. I followed the walk through @ https://xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/

Even the sample solution provided through this link produces these errors. I've  installed the **Google Admob Ads SDK** through the Android SDK manager but still no luck.

[image]

The first error is **"error: package com.google.ads.mediation.customevent does not exist"**, the following errors are similar which makes me think they're all from the same cause.

Any help would be much appreciated:)

Comment: Have you tried to download the demo  ? I downloaded the demo and run successfully,so can you provide more details?such as  build environment.

Comment: Hi LucasZ, I've managed to find a work around to this issue I'm experiencing. I've followed this walk through instead: https://montemagno.com/xamarinforms-google-admob-ads-in-android/. And I updated to the latest packages in Nuget and everything ran fine. Thanks